# How to increase the size of IEEE Conference header and also how to repeat them on all pages as header

Tags: ieeetran

[image]

```
\usepackage[T1] {fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\conf}[1]{%
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{% default title page headers, no footers
\def\@oddhead{\parbox[b]{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wd\headerbox-\columnsep}{\centering \@IEEEheaderstyle #1}}%
\let\@evenhead\@empty
\def\@oddfoot{\mycopyrightnotice}% 
\let\@evenfoot\@empty}}
\newcommand{\mycopyrightnotice}{\footnotesize 978-0-7381-1102-5/20/\$31.00 $\copyright$ 2021 IEEE\hfill}
\makeatother

%------conference Name-------%
\conf{2021 5th International Conference on Electrical Engineeri}
```

I tried to increase the size of the font by working with `\fontsize{9}{11}`
but it's making the whole header disappear. 
Also, I am not able to repeat the head on all pages.
working with overleaf

Comment: It might be easier to use `\smash` or `\raisebox` than to change `\headheight`.

Comment: BTW, `\@IEEEheaderstyle` specifies `\normalfont\scriptsize`.

Comment: Unless you are authorized to provide the conference template, don't change anything.